# Multithreading sockets with a central relay-like server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I have previously managed to implement a client-server socket script which relays messages between a single client and the server and I'm now trying to implement a multiple-client system.

More specifically, I would like to use the server as some sort of medium between two clients which retrieves information from one client and relays it to the other. I had tried to attach and send the port number of the receiving client and then extract it from the message on the server side. After that, I would try and send it to whatever socket with that port number but I ran into some trouble (as port numbers are determined at the point of sending I believe?) so now I am simply just trying to relay the sent message back to all clients. However, the problem is that the message is only being sent to the server and not being relayed to the desired client.

I had previously tried to implement a peer-to-peer system but I ran into trouble so I decided to take a step back and do this instead.

Server.py:

```
import socket, _thread, threading
import tkinter as tk

SERVERPORT = 8600
HOST = 'localhost'

class Server():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Connected = True
        self.ServerSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.ServerSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        self.ServerSocket.bind((HOST, SERVERPORT))
        self.ServerSocket.listen(2)
        self.Clients = []

    def Listen(self):
        print('Server is now running')
        while self.Connected:
            ClientSocket, Address = self.ServerSocket.accept()
            self.Clients.append(Address)
            print('\nNew user connected', Address)
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.NewClient, args=(ClientSocket,
                                                              Address))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        self.Socket.close()

    def NewClient(self, ClientSocket, Address):
        while self.Connected:
            if ClientSocket:
                try:
                    ReceivedMsg = ClientSocket.recv(4096)
                    print('Message received from', Address, ':', ReceivedMsg)
                    self.Acknowledge(ClientSocket, Address)
                    if ReceivedMsg.decode('utf8').split()[-1] != 'message':
                        ReceiverPort = self.GetSendPort(ReceivedMsg)
                        self.SendToClient(ClientSocket,ReceivedMsg,ReceiverPort)
                except:
                    print('Connection closed')
                    raise Exception
        ClientSocket.close()

    def Acknowledge(self, Socket, Address):
        Socket.sendto(b'The server received your message', Address)

    def GetSendPort(self, Msg):
        MsgDigest = Msg.decode('utf8').split()
        return int(MsgDigest[-1])

    def SendToClient(self, Socket, Msg, Port):
        Addr = (HOST, Msg) 
        for Client in self.Clients:
            Socket.sendto(Msg, Client)

def NewThread(Func, *args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        t = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(args,))
    elif len(args) > 1:
        t = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=args)
    else:
        t = threading.Thread(target=Func)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    t.join()

Host = Server()
NewThread(Host.Listen)
```

And the Client(.py):

```
import socket, threading
import tkinter as tk

Username = 'Ernest'
PORT = 8601
OtherPORT = 8602
SERVERPORT = 8600
HOST = '127.0.0.1'

class Client():
    def __init__(self, Username):
        self.Connected, self.Username = False, Username
        self.Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def Connect(self):
        print('Trying to connect')
        try:
            self.Socket.connect((HOST, SERVERPORT))
            self.Connected = True
            print(self.Username, 'connected to server')            
            Msg = MsgUI(self.Username)
            Msg.Display()            
        except Exception:
            print('Could not connect to server')
            raise Exception

    def SendMsg(self):
        if self.Connected:
            Msg = '{} sent you a message {}'.format(self.Username, OtherPORT)
            self.Socket.sendall(bytes(Msg, encoding='utf8'))
            self.GetResponse()

    def GetResponse(self, *args):
        AckMsg = '\n{} received the message'.format(self.Username)
        NMsg = '\n{} did not receive the message'.format(self.Username)
        if self.Connected:
            Msg = self.Socket.recv(4096)
            print(Msg)
            if Msg:
                self.Socket.sendall(bytes(AckMsg, encoding='utf8'))
            else:
                self.Socket.sendall(bytes(NMsg, encoding='utf8'))

class MsgUI():
    def __init__(self, Username):
        self.Username = Username
        self.entry = tk.Entry(win)
        self.sendbtn = tk.Button(win, text='send', command=Peer.SendMsg)

    def Display(self):
        self.entry.grid()
        self.sendbtn.grid()
        win.mainloop()

win = tk.Tk()
Peer = Client(Username)
Peer.Connect()
```

I want a message to be sent whenever the user presses the send button in the tkinter window, but at the same time, it is continually 'listening' to see if it received any messages.

I also previously tried to run the `GetResponse` method in the Client in another thread and instead of `if self.Connected` I used `while self.Connected` and it still didn't work.

**UPDATE**

After some helpful comments, I have edited the two files as such:
The server now holds the two sockets for each client which is run first. The server file is imported into the client file as a module. Each client file is then run and each client runs a function in the server file, requesting to use the socket. If the request is allowed (i.e. no error was thrown), the socket is connected, added to a set of clients stored in the server file and then returned to the client file. The client then uses this socket to send and receive messages.

Server.py

```
import socket, _thread, threading
import tkinter as tk

SERVERPORT = 8600
HOST = 'localhost'

class Server():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Connected = True
        self.ServerSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.ServerSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        self.ServerSocket.bind((HOST, SERVERPORT))
        self.ServerSocket.listen(2)
        self.Clients = {}

    def ConnectClient(self, Username, Port):
        Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.Clients[Username] = [Socket, Port, False]
        try:
            self.Clients[Username][0].connect((HOST, SERVERPORT))
            self.Clients[Username][2] = True
            print('Opened port for user', Username)
            return Socket
        except Exception:
            print('Could not open port for user', Username)
            raise Exception

    def Listen(self):
        print('Server is now running')
        while self.Connected:
            ClientSocket, Address = self.ServerSocket.accept()
            print('\nNew user connected', Address)
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.NewClient, args=(ClientSocket,
                                                              Address))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        self.Socket.close()

    def NewClient(self, ClientSocket, Address):
        while self.Connected:
            if ClientSocket:
                try:
                    ReceivedMsg = ClientSocket.recv(4096)
                    if b'attempting to connect to the server' in ReceivedMsg:
                        ClientSocket.send(b'You are now connected to the server')
                    else:
                        print('Message received from', Address, ':',ReceivedMsg)
                        #self.Acknowledge(ClientSocket, Address)
                        ReceiverPort = self.GetSendPort(ReceivedMsg)
                        if ReceiverPort != None:
                            self.SendToClient(ClientSocket,ReceivedMsg,
                                              ReceiverPort)
                except:
                    print('Connection closed')
                    raise Exception
        ClientSocket.close()

    def Acknowledge(self, Socket, Address):
        Socket.sendto(b'The server received your message', Address)

    def GetSendPort(self, Msg):
        MsgDigest = Msg.decode('utf8').split()
        try:
            Port = int(MsgDigest[-1])
        except ValueError:
            Port = None
        return Port

    def SendToClient(self, Socket, Msg, Port):
        Addr = (HOST, Port)
        Receiver = None
        for Client, Vars in self.Clients.items():
            if Vars[1] == Port:
                Receiver = Client
        self.Clients[Receiver][0].sendto(Msg, Addr)

def NewThread(Func, *args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        t = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(args,))
    elif len(args) > 1:
        t = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=args)
    else:
        t = threading.Thread(target=Func)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    t.join()

Host = Server()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    NewThread(Host.Listen)
```

And Client.py

```
import socket, threading, Server
import tkinter as tk

Username = 'Ernest'
PORT = 8601
OtherPORT = 8602
SERVERPORT = 8600
HOST = '127.0.0.1'

class Client():
    def __init__(self, Username):
        self.Connected, self.Username = False, Username

    def Connect(self):
        print('Requesting to connect to server')
        try:
            self.Socket = Server.Host.ConnectClient(self.Username, PORT)
            self.Connected = Server.Host.Clients[self.Username][2]
            Msg = '{} is attempting to connect to the server'.format(self.Username)
            self.Socket.sendall(bytes(Msg, encoding='utf8'))            
            ReceivedMsg = self.Socket.recv(4096)
            print(ReceivedMsg)
            Msg = MsgUI(self.Username)
            Msg.Display()            
        except Exception:
            print('Could not connect to server')
            raise Exception

    def SendMsg(self):
        try:
            if self.Connected:
                Msg = '{} sent you a message {}'.format(self.Username,OtherPORT)
                self.Socket.sendall(bytes(Msg, encoding='utf8'))
                self.GetResponse()
        except Exception:
            print('Connection closed')
            raise Exception

    def GetResponse(self, *args):
        AckMsg = '\n{} received the message'.format(self.Username)
        NMsg = '\n{} did not receive the message'.format(self.Username)
        if self.Connected:
            Msg = self.Socket.recv(4096)
            print(Msg)
            if Msg:
                self.Socket.sendall(bytes(AckMsg, encoding='utf8'))
            else:
                self.Socket.sendall(bytes(NMsg, encoding='utf8'))

class MsgUI():
    def __init__(self, Username):
        self.Username = Username
        self.entry = tk.Entry(win)
        self.sendbtn = tk.Button(win, text='send', command=Peer.SendMsg)

    def Display(self):
        self.entry.grid()
        self.sendbtn.grid()
        win.mainloop()

win = tk.Tk()
Peer = Client(Username)
Peer.Connect()
```

Now the problem is more of a python and scope problem. When trying to relay the message back to the client, I was getting a `KeyError` as the `Clients` dictionary was still empty. When making the function call to the server in the client file, it's clear that the update to the dictionary happens in the client file rather than the server file - which is in a different instance. I need a method of changing the contents of the `Clients` dictionary that is called to action by the client file but takes effect in the server file.

Comment: Your socket code is broken. TCP is a streaming protocol, there is nothing like messages. Use a well known protocol instead.

Comment: Each client will have to have a unique persistent socket for you to be able to send messages back to it.   This means the socket must be part of the server side representation of the clients.  The socket connections will need to remain open if you hope to relay other client messages back through it.  Having clients listen on other sockets is not a good idea because it interferes with NAT and firewalls.

Comment: @Daniel What do you mean by 'nothing like messages'? The messages I refer to are simply just strings to send to each client.

Comment: @DanFarrell Yes, after previous attempts I realised that the connection was being closed before the messages could be sent but I'm not sure why. From your comment, you're suggesting I create the two sockets (will only ever be two clients at a time) in the server file?

Comment: @Ernxst What Daniel means is that if you `send(b'abc')` and `send(b'def')`, the `recv(4096)` could get all 6 bytes at once `b'abcdef'`.  TCP is a streaming protocol and it is "just bytes"...you can't tell where one message ends and another begins and they can be broken up.  **You** have to define a way to tell where a message begins and ends, and buffer `recv` and extract only complete messages.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I understand, maybe I could use the port number attached onto the end of the message as a delimiter? I don't plan on sending any other integer data.

Comment: @DanFarrell See updated question, is this something like you suggested? Need a little more guidance.

Comment: Well, that's all quite complex and I feel like you're overthinking this, but I don't have a PofC for you exactly.  Python threading is one way to do this, but select() might be a more straightforward ( and due to python's GIL just as or more performant) mechanism.  https://pymotw.com/2/select/ actually hs an example "echo" server just like you want to build, and it's single threaded.  Only issue is they make the common mistake of breaking up the code on that page so it's hard to see hte whole algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you committed to multithreading?  Threads don't run concurrently in python ( due to the GIL), and while they are one way to handle concurrent operations, they aren't the only way and usually they're not the best way, unless they're the only way.  Consider this code, which doesn't handle failure cases well, but seems to work as a starting point.

```
import socket, select, Queue

svrsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
svrsock.setblocking(0)
svrsock.bind(('', 17654))
svrsock.listen(16)
client_queues = {}
write_ready=[] # we'll update this for clients only that have things in the queue
while client_queues.keys() + [svrsock] :
  readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(client_queues.keys() + [svrsock] , write_ready, [])
  for rd in readable:
    if rd is svrsock: # reading listening socket == accepting connection
      conn, addr = svrsock.accept()
      print("Connection from {}".format(addr))
      conn.setblocking(0)
      client_queues[conn] = Queue.Queue()
    else:
      data = rd.recv(1024)
      if data:
        # TODO: send to all queues
        print("Message from {}".format(rd.getpeername()))
        for sock, q in client_queues.iteritems(): 
          q.put("From {}: {}".format( rd.getpeername(), data))
          if sock not in write_ready:
            write_ready.append(sock)
  for rw in writable:
    try:
      data = client_queues[rw].get_nowait()
      rw.send(data)
    except Queue.Empty:
      write_ready.remove(rw)
      continue
```

The concept is pretty simple.  The server accepts connections; each connection (socket) is associated with a queue of pending messages.  Each socket that's ready for reading is read from, and its message is added to each client's queue. The recipient client is added into the `write_ready` list of clients with data pending, if it's not already in there. Then each socket that's ready for writing has its next queued message written to it.  If there are no more messages, the recipient is removed from the `write_ready` list.

This is very easy to orchestrate if you don't use multithreading because all coordination is inherent in the order of the application.  With threads it would be more difficult and a lot more code, but probably not more performance due to the gil.

The secret to handling multiple I/O streams concurrently *without* multithreading is `select`.  In principle it's pretty easy; we pass `select()` a list of possible sockets for reading, another list of possible sockets for writing, and a final list that for this simplified demo I completely ignore .  The results of the select call will include one or more sockets that are *actually* ready for reading or writing, which allows me to block until one or more sockets are ready for activity.  I then process all the sockets ready for activity every pass ( but they've already been filtered down to just those which wouldn't block).

There's a ton still to be done here.  I don't cleanup after myself, don't track closed connections, don't handle any exceptions, and so on.  but without having to worry about threading and concurrency guarantees, it's pretty easy to start addressing these deficiencies.

Here it is "in action".  Here for the client side I use netcat, which is perfect for layer 3 testing without layer 4+ protocols ( in other words, raw tcp so to speak).  It simply opens a socket to the given destination and port and sends its stdin through the socket and sends its socket data to stdout, which makes it perfect for demoing this server app!

I also wanted to point out, coupling code between server and client is inadvisable because you won't be able to roll out changes to either without breaking the other.  It's ideal to have a "contract" so to speak between server and client and maintain it.  Even if you implement the behavior of server and client in the same code base, you should use the tcp communications contract to drive your implementation, not code sharing.  Just my 2 cents, but once you start sharing code you often start coupling server/client versions in ways you didn't anticipate.

the server:

```
$ python ./svr.py
Connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52059)
Connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52061)
Message from ('127.0.0.1', 52061)
Message from ('127.0.0.1', 52059)
Message from ('127.0.0.1', 52059)
```

First client ( 52059):

```
$ nc localhost 17654
hello
From ('127.0.0.1', 52061): hello
From ('127.0.0.1', 52059): hello
From ('127.0.0.1', 52059): hello
```

Second client:

```
$ nc localhost 17654
From ('127.0.0.1', 52061): hello
hello
From ('127.0.0.1', 52059): hello
hello
From ('127.0.0.1', 52059): hello
```

If you need more convincing on why `select` is way more compelling than concurrent execution, consider this:  Apache is based on a threading model, in other words, the connections each get a worker thread .  nginx is based on a `select` model, so you can see how much faster that can potentially be.  Not to say that nginx is inherently better, as Apache benefits from the threading model because of its heavy use of modules to extend capabilities ( mod_php for example), whereas nginx doesn't have this limitation and can handle all requests from any thread.  But the raw performance of nginx is typically considered far higher and far more efficient, and a big reason for this is that it avoids almost all the cpu context switches inherent in apache.  It's a valid approach!

A word on scaling.  Obviously, this wouldn't scale forever.  Neither would a threading model; eventually you run out of threads.  A more distributed and high throughput system would likely use a Pub/Sub mechanism of some kind, offloading the client connection tracking and message queueing from the server to a pub/sub data tier and allowing connections to be restored and queued data to be sent, as well as adding multiple servers behind a load balancer.  Just throwing it out there.  You might be pleasantly surprised how well `select` can scale ( cpu is so much faster than network anyway that it's likely not the bottleneck).

Comment: Brilliant. I had come across select before but I thought I'd first try something with threading before learning something new but this seems far simpler. Thank you for your help +1. Now I only have one further question, how would I buffer the server to wait until both clients have connected to the server before attempting to send messages back? Currently, the second client does not receive the message sent by client 1 because they haven't connected yet. I've tried waiting until the length of writeable is > 1 but need further guidance...

Comment: If you saved every message a client sent to a universal "all messages" list ou could then add that list of messages to new clients' newly created queues.  The order matters: you would want to make sure that they didn't get the same message twice in the case that messages came in at the same time they connected.  Of course, the next problem would be that the list would grow indefinitely, so you might have to impose some size constraint on the list of historical messages.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, I see ... it makes perfect sense, thanks for everything!